# Como puedo cambiar el tamaño de mis letras sin cambiar el tamaño de mi tabla con css

Tags: php, css, font-size

actualmente tengo una tabla y alli varios td y tr:

Tabla:

```
<table border='1' style='position:absolute;top:632px;left:0px;'>
<tr>
<td colspan='3' style='width:300px;text-align:center;'><b>Materiales</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='width:100px;text-align:center;'>Descripción</td>
<td style='width:100px;text-align:center;'>ítem</td>
<td style='width:100px;text-align:center;'>Cant.</td>
</tr>";
while($crowmate = mysqli_fetch_array($matiu)){      
        
        $descrimate=$crowmate['descrimate'];
        $cantidad=$crowmate['cantidad'];
        $codmat=$crowmate['codmat'];
$tabla.="
<tr>
<td style='width:150px;'>$descrimate</td>
<td style='width:100px;text-align:center;'>$codmat</td>
<td style='width:100px;text-align:center;'>$cantidad</td>
</tr>";
}
$tabla.="
</table>
```

A esa tabla le tengo un estilo:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 500px;
    color:#0f0f0f;
}

th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 2px;
    font-size:7px;
    height:2;
}
```

Lo que estoy buscando hacer es poder aumentar el tamaño de las letras pero sin que se aumente el tamaño de la tabla, osea los th y td.

De que forma podría hacer eso con css?

Si se fijan tengo un tamaño font-size:7px; pero es muy pequeño quisiera ponerlo a 8 o 9 pero que toda la tabla quede del mismo tamaño, solo que aumente la letra, el problema es que cuando aumento de tamaño la letra también se agranda la tabla y ya esta en una posición especifica dentro del reporte y no quiero que se mueva de allí.

Comment: Pero sí aumentas el tamaño de la letra y por ello la cadena de texto no cabe en la celda, ¿qué quieres que ocurra?

Comment: Es que actualmente veo que en mi tabla en cada TR y TD tengo espacio de sobra para agrandar la letra, el problema es que cuando agrando la letra tambien se agranda la tabla. lo que estoy buscando es que cuando agrande la letra a un tamaño justo que entre en toda la tabla esta misma no cambie su tamaño.